# UpdateByQueryRequest serialize has bug

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, serialization, deserialization

When I use the serialize method that the UpdateByQueryRequest provided, the output is not complete.
The request is
`{"query":{"term":{"subjectId":{"value":592}}},"script":{"params":{"businessTypeId":2},"lang":"painless","source":"ctx._source.subjectShared.add(params.businessTypeId)"}}`
but the output is
`{"query":{"term":{"subjectId":{"value":592}}},"script":{"params":{"businessTypeId":2`
and below is how I do the serialization.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiAtC.png)

The version of es is 8.5.1

I try to increase the size of the outputstream, but the result is all the same.